# How add a 'Star *' after a django ModelForm CharField?

Tags: django, django-models, modelform, django-forms

i have some necessary fields in my django ModelForm. How can i add a red star (*) after the required fields ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm going to assume you want this to happen automatically, so here's one of a few different ways:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">{{ field.label_tag }}
    {% if field.field.required %}
        <span class="required">*</span>
    {% endif %}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you can style the asterisk using CSS.

Or, you can add the asterisk using CSS instead if you want:

```
<style type="text/css">
    span.required:after { content: '*'; }
</style>
{% for field in form %}
    <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}">
    {% if field.field.required %}
        <span class="required">{{ field.label_tag }}</span>
    {% else %}
        {{ field.label_tag }}
    {% endif %}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

This one is probably a better option if you want to do other things with the required field as well.

However, if you will not be accessing the fields individually (such as using {{ form.as_p }}), then you can add a property to your ModelForm:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

That will define all fields that are required as having the 'required' class (and thus, you can use the CSS code I mentioned above to add an asterisk (or whatever else you want to do with it).

Comment: i'm using {{ form.as_p }} in my template and i can't access required fields in the way you wrote
Is there any way to customize a html block after some fields in ModelForm ?

Comment: @Kozet: {{ form.as_p }} is fine if you're happy the the HTML that it generates but if you want to modify it then you need to write your own form HTML with each field individually.

Comment: @Kozet: Edited my answer for your situation.

Comment: Just one small improvement on this excellent answer: Since you manually write out the label tag, you can use {{field.label }} instead of {{ field.label_tag }} inside the span.required to avoid nesting labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `jQuery` in order to select the label or append to it.

for example if you have this bootstrap form

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" required="required">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Then if  you want to add the star to the required fields.

```
$('input,textarea,select').filter('[required]').parent().parent().find("label").append("*");
```

Also you may want to specify a class for the required fields labels so you can make them bold or something

```
$('input,textarea,select').filter('[required]:visible').parent().parent().find("label").addClass("required_label");
```