# How can I include a "* required field." message in all forms with required fields?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

I'm using django-crispy-forms with `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap3'`. My templates looks like this (this is an example of the sign up form, but I have a lot of forms in my templates):

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<h1>Sign up</h1>
<form action="/accounts/signup/" method="POST" role="form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sing up</button>
</form>
```

In the rendered pages, the required fields appear correctly with an * near it to indicate that they are required, but no message appears explaining what an * means.

In my case, I'm dealing with users that are sometimes not very tech-firendly, so they might not know what an * means. I would like to show a `* required field.` message in the top of all forms with required fields.

I could put a `<p>* required field.</p>` line in the beginning of each form, but I would like to know if there is a more elegant and DRY way to do it.

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How add a 'Star \*' after a django ModelForm CharField?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235201/how-add-a-star-after-a-django-modelform-charfield)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `uni_form.html` template with a custom one.

https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap3/uni_form.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the django crispy forms documentation:
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/crispy_tag_forms.html#change-required-fields

You will need to override the field template, that is your only option, unless you use a css hack (maybe something :before and :after for the asterisk element).

Your other option is to use the HTML crispy forms element, to make a notice at the top of your form:

```
HTML('<strong>Fields marked with * are required</strong>')
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to either add <p class="req_legend" style="display: none;">* required field.</p> to every form and add a js which changes its display property if required fields are found.
Here is a jquery example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.requiredField').length > 0) {
    $('p.req_legend').show();
  }
});
```

Or go full javascript and add <p> element to your only if you find a requiredField, you can than do this in a javascript that you add to the Media class of your forms